# How to Login Vtiger from my Android Application using Webservice

Tags: android, web-services, vtiger

I am using vtiger CRM - 5.4.0. I want to a create an Android Application to access Vtiger from  my Android Mobile. How to call a webservice from my Android Application to login,create record in Viger. Is it any special webservice available in Vtiger?

****Note:**** Also i tried to login like([Webservices tutorials](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/WebServices_tutorials)) using HttpUrlConnnection in Android.I got challenge token,while login error returns as "invalid token or token expired".some other webservice available for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vtiger provides Web service Client library for Java and java script.To download vtwsclib-1.4 library and its documentation go [here](http://forge.vtiger.com/frs/?group_id=181&release_id=573). This API provides all web service operations.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You want the vTiger android application like **anCRM vtiger** ?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xirgosoft.vtigercrm

if yes, you have the challenge token you can go ahead with the login. The access key field in the login operation is the md5 checksum of the concatenation of the challenge token and the user's own access key. The login operation, as opposed to getchallenge, is a post request.